# eclipse refactoring: move multiple static methods and/or fields

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Is it possible to move mutliple static methods and/or multiples static fields on one shot ?

```
public final class ClassA { 
    public static final String CONSTANTE_A = "CONSTANTE_A";
    public static final String CONSTANTE_B = "CONSTANTE_B";

    public static void methodA() {
        // statements....
    }

    public static void methodB() {
        // statements....
    }
}

public final class ClassB { 
// empty class
}
```

I would like to be able to select methodA, methodB, CONSTANTE_A and CONSTANTE_B, and do a "move..." to ClassB

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Expand until you see the static methods or varibles. Select all that you want to move. Right click. Select Refactor. Then choose the class where you want to move. Click OK. That will not just copy and paste but will refactor (update references to those methods and variables).

Comment: I think this is a better answer because it also do the refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to drag and drop the variables in Eclipse's package explorer.
Expand ClassA until you see your static variables listed under your class and select both of them -- control + click (pc) or command + click (mac).  Then just drag them to the desired destination class.

Comment: +1 never noticed you could expand beyond class level in package explorer.

Comment: That is equivalent of copy & paste the fields and methods. Therefore no refactoring is done...

Comment: No refactoring is done when doing this. Meaning, all references to ClassA will break. They will not be updated to ClassB. Using "Refactor -> Move... -> ClassB" after the selection will update all references.